# Aggregating overlapping "all-previous-events" features from time series data - in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-mining, data-extraction

My problem is pretty general and can probably be solved in many ways. But what is a smart way considering time and memory?

I have time series data of user interactions of the following form:

```
cookie_id     interaction
---------     -----------
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_banner*
1234          did_something
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_and_clicked_banner*
...           ...
```

I want it to train models predicting whether a user will click on a banner or not whenever a banner is displayed (i.e. the interactions marked with *). To do this I need to aggregate all previous interactions whenever a point of interest (either `viewed_banner` or `viewed_and clicked_banner`) shows up in the feed:

```
cookie_id     interaction
---------     -----------
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_banner               <- point of interest

cookie_id     interaction
---------     -----------
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_banner
1234          did_something
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_and_clicked_banner   <- point of interest
```

This is the core of the problem: Splitting the data up into overlapping groups! After doing this each group can then be aggregated into for instance:

```
cookie_id   did_something   viewed_banner   viewed_and_cli...   clicked?
---------   -------------   -------------   -----------------   --------
1234        1               0               0                   no
1234        3               1               0                   yes
```

Here the numbers in `did_something` and `viewed_banner` are the counts of these interaction (not including the point of interest), but other kind of aggregation could be performed as well. The `clicked?` attribute just describes which of the two kinds of "point of interest" was the last interaction in the interaction feed.

I have tried to look at Pandas `apply` and `groupby` methods, but can not come up with something that generates the desired overlapping groups.

The alternative is to use some for-loops, but I would rather not do that if there is a simple and efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me how your desired output is being generated. Is the `did_something` column the number of cumulative `did_somethings` under `interaction` from the data for that user up to that point? Also why is `viewed_banner` a 0 for the first row in the desired output?

Comment: can you explain how you do the count in detail.

Comment: Sorry. Can see that I missed some details. I have now tried to explain it in more details. Thanks for pointing out exactly what I missed out @TomAugspurger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried, I think it need more data to verify the code:

```
data = """cookie_id     interaction
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_banner*
1234          did_something
1234          did_something
1234          viewed_and_clicked_banner*
"""

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
flag = df.interaction.str.endswith("*")
group_flag = flag.astype(float).mask(~flag).ffill(limit=1).fillna(0).cumsum()
df["interaction"] = df.interaction.str.rstrip("*")
interest_df = df[flag]

def f(s):
    return s.value_counts()

df2 = df.groupby(group_flag).interaction.apply(f).unstack().fillna(0).cumsum()
result = df2[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
result["clicked"] = interest_df.interaction.str.contains("clicked").reset_index(drop=True)
print result
```

output:

```
  did_something  viewed_and_clicked_banner  viewed_banner clicked
0              1                          0              0   False
1              3                          0              1    True
```

The basic idea is split the dataframe into groups:

- odd groups are continuous rows without `*`
- even groups are only one row with `*`

It assume that the first row in the dataframe is without `*`.

Then do `value_counts` for every group and combine the results into a dataframe. `cumsum()` the counts and drop even rows will get the right counts.

I don't know how the `clicked` column is calculated. Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: Wow! Pretty complex, but it was such a non-iterating solution I was looking for. Thanks!